# Trying to disable button in React.js based on null data in the function

Tags: reactjs, typescript

My add button works when it comes to adding my data to my form but I am trying to disable the button if there is no data. Currently if I click add without no data selected it goes to my form with no data. My path to my form and sending data works fine but cant figure out to disable if its blank.

```
    const [customersToAdd, setCustomersToAdd] = useState<Array<Customers>>([]);
   const [customerError, setCustomerError] = useState<string>('');

function onOk() {
     /** This code I added to try and disable Add button
        if (customersToAdd.length == 0) {
         let customerError = null;
         customerError = (<div className='has-error'>"Please add at least one customer."</div>);
      }
      setCustomerError(customerError);  **/ 

      onAdd(customersToAdd)
   }
   
   function onAddCustomer(customerId: string) {      
      const customerFound = searchResults.data.find(result => result.customerId === customerId);
      if (typeof (customerFound) !== 'undefined') {
         const notAdded = typeof (customersToAdd.find(tmp => tmp.customerId === customerId)) === 'undefined'
         if (notAdded) {
            const newCustomer: Customer = {
               customerId: customerFound.customerId,
               customerName: customerFound.customerName
            }
            const newCustomersToAdd = customersToAdd.concat(newCustomer)
            setCustomersToAdd(newCustomersToAdd)
            setCustomerError(customerError); /** Added for Disable button **/
         }
      }
   }

<h3 className='h3 heading'>Customers to add</h3>
      {customerError} /** Displaying error message **/
      {customersToAddSection}
      <section className='btn-wrapper-c'>
         <StyledButton isPrimary={true} onClick={onOk} isDisabled={customerError}>Add</StyledButton> /** isDisabled used for disabling button **/
         <StyledButton onClick={onCancel} isMinor={true}>Cancel</StyledButton>
      </section>
```